# Broken Pointer in My HashTable or I'm Missing Something?

Tags: c, pointers, hashtable

Here's my code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct DF
{
    char str[101];
    int D;
    struct DF *next;
} DF;
DF *df[5];

int hash (char str[])
{
    int sum=0, len=strlen (str);
    for (int x=0; x<len; x++) sum+=str[x];
    
    return sum%5;
}

DF* ND (char str[])
{
    DF *node=(DF*) malloc (sizeof (DF));
    strcpy (node->str, str); node->D=1;
    node->next=NULL;
    
    return node;
}

void add (char str[])
{
    int idx=hash (str);
    if (df[idx])
    {
        DF *temp=df[idx];
        while (temp) temp=temp->next;
        temp=ND (str);
    }
    else df[idx]=ND (str);
}

int main (void)
{
    char str1[]="The"; add (str1);
    char str2[]="App"; add (str2);
    
    if (df[4])
    {
        printf ("[4] %s", df[4]->str);
        DF *temp=df[4]->next;
        while (temp)
        {
            printf (" -> %s", temp->str);
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        puts ("");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Please pay attention to `void add (char[])`, why the output is not `[4] The -> App`? Even when I changed `DF *temp=df[idx];` to `DF *temp=df[idx]->next;` it makes no difference. But if I change it the function to this,

```
void add (char str[])
{
    int idx=hash (str);
    if (df[idx])
    {
        DF *temp=df[idx];
        while (temp->next) temp=temp->next;
        temp->next=ND (str);
    }
    else df[idx]=ND (str);
}
```

It prints out `[4] The -> App`. So, what's the difference between those 2 algorithms?

Comment: I personally find it very hard to understand / read your code. Could you add some comment lines, so other people know what the program should be doing?

Comment: @BlayerBond it is not needed, it is enough to read the code to see the problem

Comment: @bruno, to be sure that I am addressing the right problem, it would be nice to know what `DF` (dataframe?), `D` (data?) and `ND` (new data?) are, without going through the whole code for that, but maybe that's just because I haven't made a HashTable in C myself :/

Comment: @BlayerBond I agree the field *D* is obscure/useless because only set to 1. For the rest yes to implement a hashtable is a good exercise, and there are lot of way to do (for instance when there are too much elements the array of list of synonym can be grow producing a rehash)

Comment: Oh sorry, it was actually part of my assignment and I'm curious about that part, like why it's working like that. And for the variables, I use `DF` because the assignment title is "Duplicate Friends", and `D` is just pressed randomly, and for ND, yes it is meant for new data.

Comment: When we do `int i = 4; int j = i; j = j + 1;` is `i` 4 or 5?

Comment: @user253751 both `hash("The")`and `hash("App")` value 4, they are synonym => the problem occurs when the list of synonym is not modified by the first way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the first way :

> ```
> temp=ND (str);
> ```

just assign a local variable, so it has no impact outside the function out of the fact you have a memory leak (but the list is not modified, the element is not added)

but in the second way :

> ```
> temp->next=ND (str);
> ```

modifies the linked list

To work you can modify the first way to do :

```
void add (char str[])
{
    int idx=hash (str);
    if (df[idx])
    {
        DF **temp=&df[idx];
        while (*temp) temp=&(*temp)->next;
        *temp=ND (str);
    }
    else df[idx]=ND (str);
}
```

but this is complicated for nothing except if you want to remove the `if` :

```
void add (char str[])
{
    DF ** temp=&df[hash(str)];
    
    while (*temp)
      temp=&(*temp)->next;
    *temp=ND (str);
}
```

Note to add a new cell at the end of the list of synonym is useless, you do not have global order, you can directly do :

```
void add (char str[])
{
    DF * temp=ND (str);
    int idx=hash (str);

    temp->next = df[idx];
    df[idx] = temp;
}
```

In *ND* :

> ```
> strcpy (node->str, str); node->D=1;
> ```

is dangerous because *str* can be too long to be saved in `node->str`, you can use *strncpy*

At contrarian when the string to save is small you lost memory.

What about to not use an array for the field *str* but a `char*` and duplicate the string (`strdup`for instance) ?

In *hash* you go through the string two times, you do not need to compute *strlen* and can use

```
for (int x=0; str[x] != 0; x++) sum+=str[x];
```

Comment: Can you explain about memory leak you talking about?

Comment: So `temp->next=ND (str)` modifies the linked list because it is **pointing** to `next`, am I correct? Because it is the same as `(*temp).next=ND (str)` right?

Comment: @LastSecond959 *temp* if not valuing NULL comes from a previous add, so `temp->next=ND (str)` modifies the field *next* of an old cell. Yes `temp->` and `(*temp).` are identical, the first is a shortcut of the second